# Mysql difference between (select a.id from table a) and (select table.id from table)

Tags: mysql, sql

what is difference between two method below:

- Memory
- Performance

A:

```
select table.id from table
```

B:

```
select a.id from table a
```

thanks (sorry if my question is duplicate).

Comment: Basically, the statement `FROM <yourTable> <name>` allows you to refer to the table with the name you give it in that request. Useful if you have long table names.

Comment: Less typing is the only difference.

Comment: @jarlh Not 100% true. It is required when joining a table to itself in order to be able to identify which instance is which.

Comment: @theblitz, true! (But I see no join here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference at all.

Using aliases is just for your convenience. If you want to save typing the complete table name.

Another usage is if you join the same table twice. Then you need alias names  to distinguish between the tables.